# messed up with publishProgress method while using it in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to implement simple internal data storage code.In it I want to show `ProgressDialog` for some background process which will increment by 5 while calling `publishProgress()`. But it gives me error like the following,

```
The method publishProgress(R.integer...) in the type AsyncTask<String,R.integer,String> is not applicable for the arguments (int)
```

following is the code.

```
public class loadSomeStuff extends AsyncTask<String, integer, String>
{
    ProgressDialog dailog;              
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        //example of setting up something
        dailog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dailog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dailog.setMax(100);
        dailog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
        String collected=null;
        FileInputStream fis=null;

        for(int i=1; i<=20; i++)
        {
            publishProgress(5);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        dailog.dismiss();
        try {
            fis=openFileInput(FileName);
            byte[] dataArray = new byte[fis.available()];
            while(fis.read(dataArray)!= -1)
            {
                collected=new String(dataArray);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                fis.close();
                return collected;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...progress)
    {
        dailog.incrementProgressBy(5);

    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        DataResults.setText(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            // some stuff
        }

Comment: but why? I want to pass the int value to increment progress bar by 5..

Comment: @DigveshPatel Your suggestion is not correct, this is not about using String for progress.

Comment: you shoud use `Integer` instead of integer in `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics cannot use value types so your AsyncTask needs to use `Integer`:

```
extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
```

Comment: Ok but again it shows error like,,,  "The method publishProgress(R.integer...) in the type AsyncTask<String,R.integer,String> is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)"

Comment: Where does `R.` come from? Do you have some mix up with namespaces? Try using full name of the class: 'java.lang.Integer'.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
```

`Integer` with a capital `I`

Answer (score 0):

Alright I think you may have messed up with some namespaces. Here is what you need to do

1. Organize your imports <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. make sure there is no invalid import. it may have happned if you **copy & paste** code from any other source.
2. Clean your project.
3. `AsyncTask` should look like this:

   `public class LoadSomeStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>`

Let me know if you still cant resolve it .

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code on my machine and its working fine without any error.

You can check now with my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    loadSomeStuff objSomeStuff = new loadSomeStuff();
    objSomeStuff.execute();


}



public class loadSomeStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
    ProgressDialog dailog;              
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        //example of setting up something
        dailog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dailog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dailog.setMax(100);
        dailog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
        String collected=null;
        FileInputStream fis=null;

        for(int i=1; i<=20; i++)
        {
            publishProgress(5);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        dailog.dismiss();
        try {
            fis=openFileInput("");
            byte[] dataArray = new byte[fis.available()];
            while(fis.read(dataArray)!= -1)
            {
                collected=new String(dataArray);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                fis.close();
                return collected;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...progress)
    {
        dailog.incrementProgressBy(5);

    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        //DataResults.setText(result);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

simple answer is that
in the Question Code Mention is

1. **AsyncTask< String, integer, String>**

But change that for progress updated

2. **AsyncTask< String, Integer, String>**

if use AsyncTask**< String, String, String>** then should be Cast into Interger for 
progress update.